# Laravel 5.2 before send / root fires check condition

Tags: php, laravel

I seem to remember in a former version of laravel you could set some logic which fired before the roots were hit. What I am looking to do is:

```
if(Auth::check())
{
    if(!Auth::user()->email || is_null(Auth::user()->email))
    {
        return redirect('/dashboard')->with('error', 'You have not provided an email address');
    }
}
```

Reason being that I have a social login and Twitter logins do not provide an email address nor do some Facebook logins.

If you can think of a better option than redirecting the user to the dashboard and am add email form please share it, as on registration I send out a welcome email via an event handler and listener and it would save me putting the same logic in the controller before firing the event.

Comment: add this in your middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware) that does this check, or you could just add it as another condition in the application's existing `Authenticate` middleware.

Here is the default `Authenticate` middleware in Laravel 5.2, with your code added to it. (you should be able to find this file in `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php`.)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Authenticate
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            }
            return redirect()->guest('login');
        }

        /* YOUR ADDED CODE STARTS HERE */

        // Note that you don't need to call `Auth::check` because
        // `Auth::guest` has already been called above and has returned
        // `false` in order to get here.

        if(!Auth::user()->email || is_null(Auth::user()->email))
        {
            return redirect('/dashboard')->with('error', 'You have not provided an email address');
        }

        /* YOUR ADDED CODE ENDS HERE   */

        return $next($request);

    }

}
```